# Subtract DateTimes in IQueryable query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iqueryable

Hello I'm trying to subtract two DateTimes in my query and compare defference with timeInterval,but I get exeption:

```
 <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
 <ExceptionMessage>System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)</ExceptionMessage>
 <ExceptionType>System.NotSupportedException</ExceptionType>
```

C# code:

```
 producerRelations = producerRelationRepository.Query().Fetch(c => c.Order).
                Where(c => c.Order.CreatedBy == login).
                Where(c=>currentDate.Subtract(c.RouteUnit.DtStart.Value).TotalMinutes<timeInterval);
```

How I can subtract dates in my code?

Answer (score 0):

use `AsEnumerable`

```
 producerRelations = producerRelationRepository.Query().Fetch(c => c.Order).
                Where(c => c.Order.CreatedBy == login).AsEnumerable().
                Where(c=>currentDate.Subtract(c.RouteUnit.DtStart.Value).TotalMinutes<timeInterval);
```

Or you need to use [`EntityFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions_methods.aspx)

Comment: <Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DiffMinutes(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.NotSupportedException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>

Comment: @Abbath you better include `currentDate.HasValue && c.RouteUnit.DtStart.HasValue ` in your where clause before you do `DiffMinutes`

Comment: y dont u just convert the date time to milliseconds and then subtract them and then convert the milliseconds back to date time

Comment: for what convert to miliseconds? I use minits and timeIntervalis double value